# What is the best approach to save multiple temperature-curves (which are measured at the same time) in a Database using Rails and SQL

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, timeline, multiple-tables

what is the best approach to save multiple temperature-curves by using Ruby On Rails and a SQL-database. The temperature curves are are measured at the same time. And the time for each measured value musst be stored in seconds.

This picute show my problem in an UML. But the assoziation between timeline and curve-measurment isn't correct. Each timeline-value can have several curve-measurments but not in the same curve. In the same curve alle timeline-values must be unique.

[image: Pic 1]

In this solution all timeline-values can have several curve-measurments. This ist correct but in this picutre a timeline-value can have several curve-mesaurments in the same curve and that is wrong.

[image: Pic 2]

I hope you understand my problem and you can give me some hint to a better approach.

Comment: What is actually the point of Timeline as automomus concept in the first place? Wouldn't it be enough to add a simple timestamp to each CurveMeasurement instance (in addition to "value")? If I get it right, some measurements are captured in certain points in time and assigned to a curve? Is this Curve just a visualisation tool? I think an additional problem here is cyclic nature of the relationships and all the problems it causes (redundancy and complicated maintainability). And finnaly - What is meant by Dataset? I see is on completely another level of abstraction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your `CurveMeasurement` should be a join between `Curve` and `Timeline`:

```
class Curve < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :curve_measurements
  ...
end

class Timeline < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :curve_measurements
  ...
end

class CurveMeasurement < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :curve
  belongs_to :timeline

  validates :curve_id, uniqueness: { scope: :timeline_id }
  validates :timeline_id, uniqueness: { scope: :curve_id }
  ...
end
```

The important parts for your requirements are the uniqueness scopes in the CurveMeasurement model - this ensures that you can't have more than one measurement for a given curve at a given timeline point.

---

It would also be possible to do this without the timeline value being a separate model:

```
class Curve < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :curve_measurements
  ...
end

class CurveMeasurement < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :curve

  validates :timeline_value, uniqueness: { scope: :curve_id }
  ...
end
```

If you wanted to enforce a discrete set of `timeline_value`s, you can use further validations: either `numericality` or `inclusion` (see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html )

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, a measurement for a given curve is a value, measured at a specific time.  And you want to be able to find all values, for all curves, at any given time.

At the same you want to be able to constrain there is only measurement per time, per curve. You can specifically do that in your second model as well.

In your model, your `curve_measurements` would look like

```
t.curve_id
t.timeline_id
t.value
```

You can then specify a constraint (depends on your database, that the combination `curve_id, timeline_id` has to be ok.

One wonders, if `Timeline` offers nothing more than just the time in seconds, why not drop that level of indirection?

Granted, if you have `Timeline` you can just write `timeline.curve_measurements`, but if you drop the necessity of the timelines table, and just add the time (or timeline) value directly to the `curve_measurements` table, your table would look something like

```
t.curve_id :integer, references: curves
t.measured_at :time
t.value
```

and then to get all measurements at a certain time, just write `CurveMeasurement.where(:measured_at => ....)`

Which is easier to query (one join less). Also to make sure there is only measurement per curve, per time, you just have to add the similar constraint, specifying that the curve_id, measured_at combination has to be unique.